# Why doesn't my F# map implementation compile

Tags: dictionary, f#, tail-recursion

I've started learning F# and I'd like to write my own map function using tail-recursion.  Here is what I have

```
let my_map ff list =
    let rec mapAcc ff_inner list_inner acc =
        match list_inner with
        | [] -> acc
        | front::rest -> mapAcc( ff_inner rest (ff_inner(front) :: acc) ) //error
    mapAcc ff list []
```

It would be called like this:

```
let list = my_map (fun x -> x * 2) [1;2;3;4;5] // expect [2;4;6;8;10]
```

I get an compilation error message on the second condition that says `Type mismatch. Expecting a     'a     but given a     'b list -> 'a -> 'a     The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and ''b list -> 'a -> 'a'`

I don't know what this error message means.  I'm not sure how this can be infinite if I am passing the `rest` in the recursive call to mapAcc.

*Note: I realize I'm rebuilding the list backwards.  I'm ignoring that for now.*

Comment: +1 for a clearly-asked question.  I'd like to point out that you don't need ff_inner at all, because ff is in scope in the inner recursive function.  Then your tail-recursive call looks like `mapAcc rest (ff front :: acc)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the parenthesis when the function calls itself:

```
let my_map ff list =
    let rec mapAcc ff_inner list_inner acc =
        match list_inner with
        | [] -> acc
        | front::rest -> mapAcc ff_inner rest (ff_inner(front) :: acc)
    mapAcc ff list []
```

otherwise everything contained there is interpreted as a single parameter and `ff_inner` as a function call with the rest as parameters.

Comment: huh?  That was easy.  I put in the parentheses to make the code more readable.  I didn't think that was the problem.